# How to solve current source prb W/O using Nodal Analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source

I have the full solution to this problem, but it is using nodal analysis. 
I am not a fan of Nodal Analysis. Is there a different approach to this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is an alternative to this problem.  First, note that you have three resistors in parallel with each other.  Put 4k in parallel with 10k which gives you 2.857kOhms.  Then, take 2.857kOhms in parallel with 3kOhms and that will give you 1.463kOhms.  Finally, you can multiply 1.463kOhms to 10mA and you will get a voltage of 14.6V.  The current is in the opposite direction as conventional current flow so the voltage potential will be -14.6V across 10kOhms resistor.  The potential voltage will be the same at all nodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxMUq4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have one question so we get -14.6V for 10KOhms because the voltage is same in parallel correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  As I mentioned in the above post, the voltage potential will be the same at all nodes.  There is no voltage divider in this circuit since there is no resistor in parallel with each other.  Makes sense?

Comment: There are two nodes in the circuit. One is the ground node with voltage 0, by definition. The other is at -14.6 V. It is not correct to say "voltage potential will be the same at all nodes".

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6PtbK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a multitude of ways you could approach this problem. The method I would have gone for is simply combining the resistances of the three parallel resistors to get one equivalent resistance. 
$$
3k\Omega || 4k\Omega || 10k\Omega  = 1460 \Omega
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVMuuH.png)</sup>

From there, \$V= IR\$, so

$$
V = 10mA * 1460 \Omega    
$$
$$  
V = 14.6 V
$$

Another method is to use the current divider formula:

$$
I_n = I_{total} \frac{R_{total}}{R_n}
$$

Another method that sprung to mind is to calculate the current through a single resistor. This one takes a little more thought, but in essence, the current through a resistor is going to be proportionate to the current through the entire network and the other resistances. 
$$
I_{R1} = I_{total}\frac{R_{other}}{ R_1 + R_{other}}
$$
$$
I_{R1} = 10mA\frac{4\Omega || 10\Omega}{ 3000 \Omega + 4\Omega || 10\Omega}
$$
$$
I_{R1} = 10mA\frac{2857 \Omega}{ 3000\Omega + 2857 \Omega}
$$
$$
I_{R1} = 10mA\frac{2857 \Omega}{5857 \Omega}
$$
$$
I_{R1} = 10mA * 0.48779
$$
$$
I_{R1} = 4.8779 mA
$$
Then, from \$V=IR\$
$$
V = 4.8779 mA * 3000\Omega
$$
$$ 
V = 14.63 V
$$
At this point you've already accepted another answer. Finished it 'cause I was already close to done. Hopefully this helps some.

Comment: You solved it correctly except for the fact that the voltage is negative because of the direction of current or simply the passive sign convention.

Comment: Yes, this is just solving for the voltage drop across the resistor, not for the 'absolute' voltage relative to ground. Which is actually what the question asks for, even though the answer bank doesn't reflect that. The question asks specifically for the *magnitude* of the voltage across the resistor, which is an absolute value, not a +/-.

Comment: I understand your point. Although I still look at it as the voltage across the resistor with respect to ground, not the absolute value. Semantics ha!